# Hibernate Envers Audit table with no suffix

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to save my audits table in another schema but keeping the tables with the same name of the audited table. I had no problem changing the suffix or using another schema, but when I set the suffix to a empty string I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.logique...User
```

I'm guessing this error is happening because I have two tables with the same name (but in different schemas), I set the "org.hibernate.envers.default_schema" and the "hibernate.default_schema" parameter correctly, I was not expecting this  problem.

Comment: So you have your JPA non-audited entities in the database's default schema and you've got your Envers audited entity tables in another explicitly set schema?  What version of Hibernate?

Comment: Hi @Naros! Thanks again for helping =). Exactly that, I have my non-audited entities in the database's default schema and mine Envers audited entity tables in another explicitly set schema. I'm using hibernate 4.3.11-FINAL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Hibernate performs its metadata collection process, it first reads all your annotated entity classes and registers each of them by name.  Additionally, as Envers processes its metadata and provides that information back to Hibernate, Hibernate will then in turn register each of those audited entities by name as well.

The issue here is that without providing a suffix or prefix, Hibernate sees the mappings from Envers as the already registered entity name because without the prefix/suffix, they're named exactly the same as the source entity they're generated from, causing this error.

```
org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping
```

There is a workaround, but it can be tedious depending on the number of audited entities you may have.  I have tested this on 5.x and I likely suspect this should work on 4.3.x.

1. Set either the `audit_table_prefix` or `audit_table_suffix` configuration properties.  This is a *must* because this is what will force the metadata from Envers to be uniquely named persistable objects to Hibernate.  Without doing this, you'll continue to get the duplicate mapping error from above.
2. For each audited entity, explicitly add an `@AuditTable` annotation where you specifically set the audit table name to be identical to the the name being generated for your entity, whether it is based on the class name or an existing `@Table` with a name attribute.

So as an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@AuditTable("my_table")
public class MyTableEntity {
  /* stuff */
}
```

So with this configuration, you will be able to have your Envers tables in one schema, the main entity tables in another, and both schemas have their tables names be identical.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Naros, thanks again for helping, sorry for taking so long to test your answer. I'm getting two warnings: "WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [alter table audit.person  drop constraint FK9brsg4fcuo22u7e7oxa9g1tqn]" and "WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [drop sequence hibernate_sequence]". Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I left the code I used to test on github, https://github.com/Teless/TesteEnvers, kept as simples as possible 2 classes and the stacktrace of both warning on the project description

Comment: I believe those warning were generate because hibernate were trying to create foreign keys between the audit tables and the entities tables (which are in another schema), am I right?

Comment: Working like a charm for Hibernate 4.3.11 (no warnings) =), thanks!

Comment: I do think we probably need to improve on this configuration for the future.  It feels a bit _hackish_ to have to use this type of configuration setup to accomplish what should have been a straight forward and simple goal.  I've added https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10975 to see what I can do long-term.